# Group By with aggregate Query is timing out MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

When I run this query on the table which has 14K records

```
select max(id) as 'id' from table_records where search_counter='0' group by Record_Date
```

it executes in **0.016** sec which returns **676 records**

The **id** column is **primary key** and its also having **unique index** defined on it

Now when I use the above query as **subquery** for example

```
select * from table_records where id in 
(select max(id) as 'id' from table_records where search_counter='0' group by Record_Date)
```

This executes forever. On my local dev machine it takes **139.511 sec** to execute on server it gets **timed out**

I am not sure what's exactly wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you pls share the result of explain for the 2nd query? Btw, you do not need to define both primary key and unique index on the same field. Did you try to rewrite the query to use a join, rather than an `in` clause?

Comment: @Shadow Can you help me out with the join query I am not able to sort it out

Comment: Try this : `select t1.id, t1.record_date from table_records t1 
inner join (select max(id) as 'id' from table_records where search_counter='0' group by Record_Date) t2 
on t1.id = t2.id;`

Comment: @Sandhurst if you shared what you tried, I could help with it, but I'm not going to code it for you. Also, you still have not shared the explain with us.

Comment: @Shadow I do not know from where to get the "explain" data. I am using MySQL Workbench and all I can share is the time the query is taking to complete

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi Thanks for your help, I have ran this one and it seems to be working perfectly fine

Comment: I have added it as an answer. :)

Comment: @Sandhurst just type the word explain in front of your select: `explain select ...`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: Thanks @Shadow I learned a new thing from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `in` run a join query

```
 select t1.id, t1.record_date from table_records t1 
 inner join (select max(id) as 'id' from table_records 
             where  search_counter='0' group by Record_Date) t2 
 on t1.id = t2.id;
```